# why is the state of my contract not changing

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am creating a study project in solidity, its a basic smart contract.

I have the following smart contract:

```
contract SmartContract {
    uint256 public contractProperty = 10;

    function changeProperty(int256 newVal) external {
        contractProperty = uint256(newVal);
    }
}
```

I am running the following test:

```
const SmartContract = artifacts.require("SmartContract");

contract('SmartContract', function(accounts) {
    var testInstance;

    it('returns correctly', () => {
        return SmartContract.deployed().then((instance) => {
            testInstance = instance;
        })
        .then(() => {
            testInstance.changeProperty(10000);
        })
        .then(() => {
            return testInstance.contractProperty();
        })
        .then((val) => {
            assert.equal(val.toString(), '10000'.toString());
        });
    });
});
```

I get an error that expected 10 to equal to 10000 meaning that the contract property doesn't change.

What am I doing wrong? Why does the state of my smart contract not change?
(Am using truffle and ganache with solidity ^0.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const SmartContract = artifacts.require('./SmartContract.sol');

require('chai').use(require('chai-as-promised')).should();

contract('SmartContract', function (accounts) {
    var testInstance;

    it('returns correctly', () => {
        return SmartContract.deployed()
            .then((instance) => {
                testInstance = instance;
            })
            .then(() => {
                return testInstance.changeProperty(10000); // return is required
            })
            .then(() => {
                return testInstance.contractProperty(); // return is required
            })
            .then((val) => {
                assert.equal(val.toString(), '10000'.toString());
            });
    });
});
```

without `{, ..., }`, we don't need require `return`

```
contract('SmartContract', function (accounts) {
    var testInstance;

    it('returns correctly', () => {
        return SmartContract.deployed()
            .then((instance) => {
                testInstance = instance;
            })
            .then(() => testInstance.changeProperty(10000))
            .then(() => testInstance.contractProperty())
            .then((val) => {
                assert.equal(val.toString(), '10000'.toString());
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: I suspect it needed to have the transaction returned?

Comment: without `return`, the `Promise Pending` is coming in next `then`